# UFW Syntax to find and delete ONE rule among 4279 UFW REJECT IN rules

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ufw, fail2ban

I've setup Fail2Ban to use UFW actions to permanently ban IPs after 1 failed attempt. What seemed like a good idea are now causing me problems as I need to remove one IP among all those ufw rules.

When using sudo `ufw status numbered` the terminal does not allow all those lines/pages to scroll through, which also would take forever, so I'm looking to find the correct command for `sudo ufw delete ....`

Fail2ban inserts the following rule:

```
Anywhere                   REJECT IN   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I already tried `sudo ufw delete REJECT IN xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and `sudo ufw delete RECEJCT IN from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to Anywhere`

**What is the correct ufw command/syntax to remove such rule when I know which IP to remove?**

As a bonus question. Am I overdoing Fail2Ban / UFW by having a permanent ban after 1 failed attempts? What is a good practise to block all thous brute-force attempts on port SSH/22

Comment: I prefer acessing ssh via VPN or port knocking than having random ssh services open for the Internet.

Comment: Sure, that's an option, but that does not help me with the current situation where I need to delete that one IP :-) Got any tip on ufw syntax to delete the IP?

Comment: Maybe try `REJECT` instead of `RECEJCT` ;-)

Comment: Or if that does not work, you can use `ufw status numbered | grep the_ip_address`  and then `ufw delete ##`.

Comment: @RoVo, Thanks for the spelling check ;-) The `ufw status numbered | grep the_ip_address worked` Will you make an answer

Comment: @RoVo, yeah it seems like an overkill/not-needed to perm-ban IPs. I'm using ED25519, disabled pwd and root, allowed only one user. Next I would consider port-knocking or changing the SSH. Probably I prefer port-knocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` to filter the `ufw status` output.

```
sudo ufw status numbered | grep the_ip_address
```

and then

```
sudo ufw delete ###
```

with `###` being the number from the first commands output.

---

As for your second question:

Imo, `fail2ban` is good as it slows down bruteforcing, but banning forever using `ufw` is not very useful as these bruteforcers don't have fixed IPs but use botnets and with every server they hacked they have one more IP.

You should:

1. Disable `root` login.
2. Disable password login or at least have **very** strong passwords.
3. Use `fail2ban`.
4. Maybe change `ssh` port.

Comment: Thank you good Sir! Saved my day

Comment: glad I could help :)